# dbexport on windows -387 - No connect permission. -111 - ISAM error: no record found

Tags: informix

I am using Informix Developer Edition 11.70 in Windows 7.  When I tried to do DBexport using the following command:

```
dbexport -c -o . cx_db
```

I get the following error:

> -387 - No connect permission.
>   -111 - ISAM error:  no record found.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The error message says that DB-Export found the database but you don't have permission to access it. Can you access the database?  How do you know? Does `dbaccess cx_db` work?  If not, find the DBA and get permission to access the database.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the command with the database administrator user? Did you install it with a non-informix user?

Also please make sure you have your Informix engine environment variables set: INFORMIXSERVER, and INFORMIXDIR. 
A simple "set" output can show you if they are set, or not.

The easiest way to do it, is setting them via setnet32 application, supplied together, and located inside your "Windows-> Programs -> Informix 11.70" section.